Chrome "Aw, Snap! error code: STATUS_BREAKPOINT" occurring in 3 different scenarios
I get the following error in Chrome: "Aw, Snap! error code: STATUS_BREAKPOINT" in two different actions (and found a third, "workbench.developerforce.com object list drop-down is crashing") when looking for help.
First scenario:
Step 2 of Creating a "Master/Detail" relationship field: When I try to "choose the related object," clicking on the dropdown list shows a 'blank' list, and then the "Aw, Snap!" error appears.
Second scenario:
Goto User Access & Permissions Assistant (Salesforce Labs app)

Analyze by Permission
Permission type: Object
Object -> When attempting to select an object, the dropdown list shows a 'blank' list and then the "Aw, Snap!" error.

For Context:

I am the System Administrator and have access to all objects/fields
Our instance has an obscene amount (1,272) of Custom Objects (I'm looking at you Certinia, fka FinancialForce)

Troubleshooting steps I have already taken (and still getting the error):

Cleared the cache
Confirmed using the current Chrome version (Version 126.0.6478.115 (Official Build) (64-bit))
Removed all Chrome extensions - restarted the computer.
Uninstalled Chrome - restarted computer, then installed Chrome.
Confirmed that neither of these situations occurs when using the Firefox browser.

The Salesforce Chat Support agent I initially spoke with had the same issue for the first scenario, but interestingly, the Salesforce Support agent who took over the case did not experience it.
I thought it might be related to the amount of memory allocated to Chrome, but that apparently isn't something that can be changed.

Good News!
Updating Chrome to (at least) Version 126.0.6478.127 (Official Build) (64-bit) has fixed the crashing issue when trying to select an object in all three of the scenarios described earlier.
